# when the base case executes it prints the value but returns None

Tags: python-3.x, function, recursion, return

``#the code needs to return the value of the recipient when the base case executes at the termination of recursion
`import math
days = int(input())
def adv(days,recipient,likes,depth):
    depth+=1
    print(" "*depth + "adv({},{})at day {} and likes are {}".format(days-4,recipient,days,likes))
    days -= 1
    if days == 0:
        #print(recipient)
        print(likes)
        #print(" "*depth + "adv({},{})at day {} and likes are {}".format(days-4,recipient,days,likes))`
here it returns recipient`
        return recipient
    else:
        likes =likes+ math.floor(recipient/2)
        adv(days,math.floor(recipient/2)*3,likes,depth)

#the variable a is supposed to receive the value of recipient but

a= adv(days+1,5,0,1)

print(a)

## it returns None

Comment: what is the code supposed to do, what is the expected input and output, please add all this in the question

Answer (score 0):

It's  because this is intended to be a recursive function, but you don't return the call when it's called from within itself. Instead, when called from inside itself, the innermost return value is discarded, and None is passed up and returned by the original invocation. You can fix it like this:

```
import math
days = int(input())
def adv(days,recipient,likes,depth):
    depth+=1
    print(" "*depth + "adv({},{})at day {} and likes are {}".format(days-4,recipient,days,likes))
    days -= 1
    if days == 0:
        return recipient
    else:
        likes =likes+ math.floor(recipient/2)
        return adv(days,math.floor(recipient/2)*3,likes,depth) #<------

a= adv(days+1,5,0,1)
print(a)
```

output:

```
5
  adv(2,5)at day 6 and likes are 0
   adv(1,6)at day 5 and likes are 2
    adv(0,9)at day 4 and likes are 5
     adv(-1,12)at day 3 and likes are 9
      adv(-2,18)at day 2 and likes are 15
       adv(-3,27)at day 1 and likes are 24
27
```